# Bootstrap data attribute(data-src) and angularjs issue

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-strap

Right now I'm working on a project in which I'm using bootstrap with angularjs. Now, the problem which I have is like, in a bootstrap based view there is data-src for example as mention below:-

```
 <span data-src="path/to/image.jpg" data-width="1000" data-height="500">
 </span>
```

which is dynamically adding img tag dynamically like this:-

```
 <span data-src="path/to/image.jpg" data-width="1000" data-height="500">
      <img alt="image here" width="1000" height="500" src="path/to/image.jpg" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px; margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 0px;">
 </span>
```

Now, the issue is that angularjs does not allow the bootstrap to dynamically add the img tag which results in breaking the styling of the entire view. Moreover, I used angular-ui for bootstrap and angular-strap but no luck.

So, if anyone has any solution of this issue then I would appreciate.

Comment: can you demonstrate issue in plunkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/COe7CyRVt5gBzXqkTMKq?p=preview

Comment: check out this I'm doing something like this. http://plnkr.co/edit/k2vvc82dBgAYzT8WhUMv?p=preview

Comment: Like, using bootstrap's data-src in angularjs context but it is not add the img tag for image to show.